# Power schematic for RP2040 & serial resistor amount

Tags: power, serial, schematic, rp2040

I am trying to design a PCB with a RP2040 microchip that is able to communicate with a SpektrumRC reciever over the SRXL2 serial protocol from a JST connection. The board will be programmed over USB and be able to receive power from either the USB connection, the JST connection, or both.

I included the Schottky diode to protect against reversed polarity. The rest mostly comes from the input example design for a minimal board design in the [RP2040 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf).

I don't know much about circuit design and I was wondering if the way that I added the serial communication and the Schottky diode in the image below was correct. With that would I be able to power a couple servos directly of the VBUS line after the Schottky diode, or is there some other way I have to do it?

On another note, for the serial communication from the JST connector, would I need to include a resistor in series before connecting the line to the chip and if so, how would I figure out what value that resistor needs to be? This is the communication protocol: https://github.com/SpektrumRC/SRXL2

[image: Current power and communication schematic for an rp2040]

Edit:
Made the change to the Schottky diode setup
[image]

Comment: Will you have the JST plugged in at the same time as the USB cable?

Comment: Not while in use normally but I would like it to still work with both plugged in

Comment: As shown the JST connector and USB connector are directly connected. This is undesirable. Each needs its own diode to VBUS if they are ever going to be plugged in simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, does everything else look right? And also do you know anything about resistors on the serial line and if I need them?

Comment: The point of the serial resistors is to moderate the IO drive strength and slew rate. Without them you can get ringing due to parasitic capacitance and inductance in the cables. I would include the resistors to be safe.

Comment: Is there a calculation that I can use to figure out what resistance I would need?